# Shift text down and induce overlap with next line

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, mdframed, overlap

I'm quite new to LaTeX, and I've got a following question:

I'd like to shift text in a single line without shifting any other part of my document. More specifically, I want it to overlap with the following mdframed text so that a part of frame's upper line is subtituted with text.

I have quickly drawn a picture in Paint that shows what I need:
[image: a rough example of what I need]

I tried to use \vspace, but it shifts everything and no overlapping occurs.

What are the other solutions? Thakns beforehand.

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used `mdframed` but I have used the very nice package `tcolorbox` to create your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=\textbf{Some overlapping text},coltitle=black,colframe=blue,colback=white,
attach boxed title to top left=
{xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white, colback=white}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```